# Sony WHX1000 M3 won't connect to Ubuntu 20.04 with VMODA BOOM PRO microphone inserted into the headphone jack

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, microphone, sony

My Sony WHX1000 M3 won't connect to the bluetooth of Ubuntu 20.04 when VMODA BOOM PRO microphone is inserted into the headphone jack. How do I make it work? Some more clarification: My PC has two ports: One for headphones only and one for the mic. When I plug the VMODA BOOM PRO into the headphone port, it doesn't work (but the Sony headphones do work and they remain connected to the Ubuntu 20.04 bluetooth). When I plug the VMODA BOOM PRO into the mic port, the Sony headphones are immediately disconnected from the bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect in BT while hooked with an AUX cable in the XM-series, so everything needs to go through the AUX cable